# При parallelStream JVM сама создает оптимальное количество потоков?

Tags: java, java-stream

При `parallelStream` JVM сама создает оптимальное количество потоков?

Comment: Да, в parallelStream() используется `n` потоков: `1` - main поток и `n-1` - потоки из ForkJoinPool'а, где `n` - количество ядер процессора.

Comment: Может ядер процессора?

Comment: Другое дело, что количество потоков, равное количеству процессоров, не всегда является самым оптимальным для решений конкретной задачи. Бывает даже, что параллелизм делает выполнение медленнее, чем вообще без параллелизма.

Comment: Вопрос читается как утверждение, почему вы так сформулировали?

Comment: Ну я спрашиваю. Правильнее ж для ядер?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov реализация с ForkJoinPool'ом используется в Oracle JDK, в других реализациях может быть по-другому. Связанный вопрос на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802463/how-many-threads-are-spawned-in-parallelstream-in-java-8